# How to improve efficiency and time-complexity of AIO Cloud Cover solution

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

Sorry for the noob question, but is there a less time expensive method to iterate through the input list, as upon submission I receive timeout errors. I tried changing the method of checking for the minimum answer by appending to a list and using min function, but as expected that didn't help at all.

Input:

```
6 3
3
6
4
2
5
```

Solution:

```
with open("cloudin.txt", "r") as input_file:
    n, covered = map(int, input_file.readline().split())
    ls = [None for i in range(100005)]
    for i in range(n-1):
        ls[i] = int(input_file.readline().strip())
ans = 1000000001
file = open("cloudout.txt", "w")
for i in range(n-covered):
    a = 0
    for j in range(covered):
        a += ls[i+j]
    if a < ans:
        ans = a
file.write(str(ans))
```

output:

```
11
```

https://orac2.info/problem/aio18cloud/
[image: Result]

Note: Blue + White indicates timeout

Comment: Please provide the problem statement inside the question as opposed to including a link (since links can rot over time).

Comment: While IO can often be a cause for performance issues, another frequent cause is algorithms with poor complexity. You’re using a quadratic time algorithm for a problem expecting linear time (computing the minimum sum subarray of a fixed size).

Comment: Thank you @kcsquared how would I do that? I'm unable to construct a linear time solution.

Comment: The name of the problem is ‘range sum query’— preprocess an array, so that given a range in an array, you can compute its sum in constant time. One way to do this is with prefix sums. I’d recommend searching for ‘range sum query’ and similar. Also, BrokenBenchmark made a useful suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

The core logic of your code is contained in these lines:

```py
ans = 1000000001
for i in range(n-covered):
    a = 0
    for j in range(covered):
        a += ls[i+j]
    if a < ans:
        ans = a
```

Let's break down what this code actually does. For each closed interval (i.e. including the endpoints) `[left, right]` from the list `[0, covered-1], [1, covered], [2, covered+1], ..., [n-covered-1, n-2]` (that is, all closed intervals containing exactly `covered` elements and that are subintervals of `[0, n-2]`), you are computing the range sum `ls[left] + ls[left+1] + ... + ls[right]`. Then you set `ans` to the minimum such range sum.

Currently, that nested loop takes `O((n-covered)*covered))` steps, which is `O(n^2)` if `covered` is `n/2`, for example. You want a way to compute that range sum in constant time, eliminating the nested loop, to make the runtime `O(n)`.

The easiest way to do this is with a prefix sum array. In Python, [itertools.accumulate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) is the standard/simplest way to generate those. To see how this helps:

```
Original Sum: ls[left] + ls[left+1] + ... + ls[right]

can be rewritten as the difference of prefix sums
   (ls[0] + ls[1] + ... + ls[right])
 - (ls[0] + ls[1] + ... + ls[left-1])

which is prefix_sum(0, right) - prefix_sum(0, left-1)
where are intervals are written in inclusive notation.
```

---

Pulling this into a separate `range_sum()` function, you can rewrite the original core logic block as:

```py
prefix_sums = list(itertools.accumulate(ls, initial=0))

def range_sum(left: int, right: int) -> int:
    """Given indices left and right, returns the sum of values of
    ls in the inclusive interval [left, right].
    Equivalent to sum(ls[left : right+1])"""

    return prefix_sums[right+1] - prefix_sums[left]
    
ans = 1000000001
for i in range(n - covered):
    a = range_sum(left=i, right=i+covered-1)
    if a < ans:
        ans = a
```

The trickiest part of prefix sum arrays is just avoiding off-by-one errors in indexes. Notice that our prefix sum array of the length-n array `ls` has `n+1` elements, since it starts with the empty initial prefix sum of `0`, and so we add `1` to array accesses to `prefix_sums` compared to our formula.

Also, it's possible there may be an off-by-one error in your original code, as the value `ls[n-1]` is never accessed or used for anything after being set?